# How to close react modal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tell me how when you click outside the window to close it? put a click on the main div, but it closes when I click even on the form input field. How to implement this idea?

```
export default () => {
    const cn = useClassName('home-page');
    const slider = useRef();


    const onNext = () => slider.current.next();
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const onStart = () => {
        setActive(true);
    };
    const closeModal = () => {
        if (active) {
            setActive(!active);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={cn()} onClick={closeModal}>
            <Carousel dotsClass="test-className" ref={slider} effect="fade">
                {dataSet.map(elem =>
                    <Slider title={elem.title} img={elem.image} onNext={onNext} onStart={onStart} key={elem.index}/>
                )}
            </Carousel>
            <LoginForm style={active ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: If you use `onClick={e => closeModal(e)}` you can use that event parameter in the function to check `e.target` / `e.currentTarget`

Comment: You can use this hook: https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/
Just with the ref of the div it will be able to know when you click outside. Also you may want to take a look at the implementation: https://github.com/Andarist/use-onclickoutside/blob/master/src/index.ts